# Should I connect metal enclosure to -V or to virtual ground?

Tags: audio, grounding, virtual-ground

I've built a headphone amplifier powered by a switch-mode 2-pin wall wart power supply. Internally a virtual ground is created by dividing and buffering the supply voltage. Input and output signals are referenced to virtual ground. I/O connector sleeves are isolated from metal enclosure.
If metal enclosure is not grounded, I obviously get 50Hz background hum, so I tried to connect enclosure to -V, then to virtual ground. In both cases the background hum was gone, but which option is "more proper"?
[image: headphone amp schematic]

Comment: Since the primary purpose of the chassis shield seems to be signal integrity, I want to say virtual ground. Looking forward to hearing what those with actual knowledge have to say.

Comment: Which ground can handle an ESD strike best?

Comment: @Jeroen3 I suppose the -V, supplied by my MeanWell power adapter, is better ESD protected than LM358 with 20Ω output resistor 

Comment: If your chassis is connected by the connector to the sleeve, it'll have to be your virtual ground or you'll be running DC through your headphones.

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis I'm using plastic connectors, so sleeves are isolated from the enclosure by default.